# Reading values from App.Config file

Tags: c#

My app.config has a structure like this:

[image]

It has the first three ones, I added `<appsettings>` section to it and then added a `key/value` to that section and trying to read it with a command like

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MYWEBSERVICE"];
```

But I get `null`. Why?

```
<appSettings>
    <add key ="MYWEBSERVICE" value ="http://mymachine.company.com/Wsmc/WebService1.asmx"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Does the setting entry look like this:  `<add key="MyKeyName" value="valuestringhere"/>`?

Comment: @DonBoitnott yes, it looks like that.  I will add an example of it to the question

Comment: it shouldn't (be null). Can you expand that section in the xml? A picture isn't very helpful :/

Comment: @alykins ok I added it to the question.

Comment: Assuming you are actually doing this? string something = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MYWEBSERVICE"]; Yes? and not "MyKeyName"

Comment: Are you calling this from a DLL? Do you add this key to the EXE.Config?

Comment: @alykins no that part is right, I was writing in pseudo so yeah I meant the same key name as the config file, I literally copy pasted it to make sure it is correct..

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear:  the file in the project is `app.config`.  When built, the file becomes `myApp.exe.config` and that file must be in the same directory as the EXE you are running.  Copying the `app.config` in there will not work.

Comment: @DevWannaBe
figured, just wanted to check xD what about your other settings... are they coming in ok? like ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["something"]

Edit: I noticed you don't have connection strings in there- but I gather you know what I mean. Those other app settings- do they come in ok

Comment: @DonBoitnott hmm right, it is NOT in the Bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the two keys match.  Right now, you have "MyKeyName" and "MYWEBSERVICE" - one of those is wrong.  Make sure that they match in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was because it is a DLL. I should have an EXE to have a app.config

Comment: You should add your configuration to the EXE.config used by your main program